# Creating a connection through sql developer using Oracle XE 10g

Tags: sql, oracle

I installed the Oracle XE 10g and am trying to create a connection with SQL Developer. The inputs are:
Connection Name: XE
Username; SYS
Password: 
Hostname: localhost
Port: 1521
SID: XE

The error: Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505
TNS: Listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor.

Please help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Is the database actually up? If so, did you start the listener after the database? You should also be supplying the `SERVICE_NAME` rather than `SID` - the value is still `XE`, but they are different things, and the listener might not know the `SID` without explicit configuration.

Comment: When I right click o the Start Database from Oracle XE menu, the command prompt says service already started. After that when I try to create a connection, I get the same error.

Comment: any idea how to fix it?? someone help please!!!!!

Comment: OK - but when you create a connection in SQL Developer there is (I think, don't have it in front of me) a radio button to choose whether to enter a SID or a service name. You need to pick service name and enter that as XE, I think?

Comment: Tried that too..doesn't work :(:(..this time says Network adapter could not establish the connection..Under Services, it shows these two are running: OracleServiceXE, OracleXETNSListener

Answer (score 0):

Inside registry key provide the path of the tnsnames.ora
i.e., Crate a key string named "TNS_ADMIN" and put the value as path of the tnsnames.ora file.